# How to generate an excel file with file attachments in the cells programmatically using Node.js or browser javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know how to generate a simple excel file using Node.js or browser javascript. However I can't find any documentations on generating an excel file where some of the cells are file attachments (not just urls). Note: The attachments data will be obtained via a 3rd party api as suppose to local files. But I don't think that should matter. Thanks!

Comment: Just as a side note, embedding files inside excel seems like an awful idea, that vastly reduces the usability to most users.  Bundling a zip or other archive seems like a much better approach, imo.

Comment: I don't really have a choice in this. But let's just say that I do, can the other approaches you have mentioned be done programmatically?

Comment: Yes, there are a number of npm based libraries for bundling zip and tar files from system directories or file streams.

Comment: The reason to embed file in the excel sheet internally is so that each file corresponds to a row in the sheet. I see the bundling you are talking about is independent of excel. It removes the relationship between each file and each row. It's not really what I need. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this?